# Changing local variables inside functions or methods in python

Tags: python

I'm extending an open source python product, but I can't change the code directly as that would make merging with upstream changes harder.

So instead of changing the function directly I want to manipulate the local variable inside the function from another place. I want to add a key to a dictionary which is created inside the function as local variable. How would I be able to change this local dic variable? Is this possible?

Take as example the below code:

```
import functools
class API(object):

    def update_resources(self, host):
        bla = sflkj
        dic = {
            'cpu': 5,
            'memory': 500
        }

class APIExtension(API):
    def update_resources(self, host):
        # But first do our changes to the function here
        # The change that I want to do is add a key: 'workload'
        # this is the function I want to change the dic variable to include workload
        super(APIExtension, self).update_resources
```

Comment: "... that would make merging with upstream changes harder." That's what git is for. Or providing a patch to externalize the variable.

Comment: If you diverge too many from upstream and change everything directly in the files of upstream, you wont be able to easily apply patches and cherry-pick. It's about openstack, which provides a way to extend the apis, so we created our own API extension which is the suggested way. We can now easily merge bug fixes without having to always manually apply patches because the files weren't matching anymore. I agree with you though, its a good point. +1ed it.

Comment: You cannot manipulate a local variable, but you can certainly manipulate the outcome somehow. Since I assume that the local variable  is used and applied somewhere in the code, that has not only a local scope, you might want to "hook" in exactly there. But without more details it is hard to help you. The other option is to overwrite update_resources completeley, without calling super.

Comment: "So instead of changing the function directly I want to manipulate the local variable inside the function from another place." This is not coherent, because the local variables **aren't** "inside the function". They **only exist while the function is running**, and are separate for each run of the function (including if another run is in progress).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  If the variable is local to the function it doesn't exist except when the function is executing.  Even if you could, it's unlikely that managing this hack would be easier than managing your custom changes to the library (or asking the library developers to change it so the variable is made accessible).

Answer (score 2):

Create a patch and send it to library authors. They will apply it to their code base and be grateful for your involvment. Just do it in a way that it can be configurable - like add new method that creates that dictionary, you'd like to extend. Then you could override that new method in your subclass and the patch won't be specific to your project.

If library owners merge your patch,  you'll be able to just use newer version of library, once it's released.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, that's what Git is for and seems the best advice. But not  an answer to the question. I still wanted to let other users see this, if they are struggling with

We are currently using git rebase, so when a new release comes out we just do a git

```
git checkout our_changes_to_upstream_branch
git rebase -i upstream/master
```

on our modified branch. This will show a list of commits we've done and let's us manually choose which commits are no longer needed. After that it will remove our changes and save it temporary to somewhere in git, then do a fast forward with upstream and after it's at the latest version of upstream, it will replay our changes on top of the latest version. If there are conflicts it will stop and you can specify if you want to manually merge or skip.

Normally at this point if there is a conflict we just skip it and create a ticket to the original commit author to make a new patch and see if the patch is still needed.

We noticed that most patches need a rewrite but that this is the cleanest way to do it. If there are any improvements would be glad to hear them!